# Enforcing 1:1 and 1:Many cardinality in denormalized warehouse table with composite Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, data-warehouse

I have a table called "`Accounts`" with a `composite primary key` consisting of 2 columns: `Account_key` and `Account_Start_date` both with the datatype `int` and another non key column named `Accountnumber(bigint).`

Account_key should have one or many `Accountnumber(bigint)` and not the other way around meaning **1 or many Accountnumber can only have 1 Account_key**. 
If you try to insert same Account_key and same Account_Start_date then the `primary key constraint` is stopping this of course because they are together primary key.

However if you insert existing Account_key with different non existing Account_Start_date then you could insert a random Accountnumber as you wish without any constraint complaining about it, **and suddenly you have rows with many to many relations between Account_key and Accountnumber and we dont want that**.

I have tried with a lot of constrains without any luck. I just don't know what I am doing wrong here so please go ahead and help me on this, thanks! 
(Note: I dont think changing the composite primary key is an option because then we will loose the slowly changing dimension date functionality)

There is another table (case) where 1 'Account_Key' can only be related to 1 'AccountNumber' meaning 1..1 relation, all other things is the same except that there should be 1..1 relation between them. 
Unique index havent work for me at least, just consider if I wanted to change `Accounts` table or put a trigger or even a Index so it will be 1..1 relation between 'Account_Key' and 'AccountNumber', ?

Comment: Start date in the key in usual.  Is it possible for one of your accounts to have more than 1 start date?

Comment: Yes, 1 Accountnumber can have more than 1 Account_start_date.

Comment: well, the first error is that, what you call Account_Key is not a key. Who creates that key? Which constraints are onto it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were an OLTP table the solution would be to properly normalize the data into two tables, but this is a DW table so it makes sense to have it all in one table.

In this case, you should add a `FOR` / `AFTER` Trigger `ON INSERT, UPDATE` that does a query against the `inserted` pseudo-table. The query can be a simple `COUNT(DISTINCT Account_Key)`, joining back to the main table (to filter on just the `AccountNumber` values being added/updated), doing a `GROUP BY` on `AccountNumber` and then `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Account_Key) > 1`. Wrap that query in an `IF EXISTS` and if a row is returned, then execute a `ROLLBACK` to cancel the DML operation, a `RAISERROR` to send the error message about why the operation is being cancelled, and then `RETURN`.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_TableName_PreventDuplicateAccountNumbers
ON dbo.TableName
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (EXISTS(
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tab.Account_Key)
   FROM   dbo.TableName tab
   INNER JOIN INSERTED ins
                    ON ins.AccountNumber = tab.AccountNumber
   GROUP BY  tab.AccountNumber
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tab.Account_Key) > 1
   ))
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISERROR(N'AccountNumber cannot be associated with more than 1 Account_Key', 16, 1);
  RETURN;
END;
```

For the "other" table where the relationship between `Account_Key` and `AccountNumber` is 1:1, you might could try doing something like:

```sql
DECLARE @Found BIT = 0;

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT tab.Account_Key, tab.AccountNumber
  FROM   dbo.TableName tab
  INNER JOIN INSERTED ins
          ON ins.Account_Key = tab.Account_Key
          OR ins.AccountNumber = tab.AccountNumber
), counts AS
(
  SELECT c.[Account_Key],
         c.[AccountNumber],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.[Account_Key
                            ORDER BY c.[Account_Key, c.[AccountNumber]) AS [KeyCount],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.[AccountNumber]
                            ORDER BY c.[AccountNumber], c.[Account_Key) AS [NumberCount]
  FROM cte c
)
SELECT @Found = 1
FROM   counts
WHERE  [KeyCount] > 1
OR     [NumberCount] > 1;

IF (@Found = 1)
BEGIN
   ROLLBACK;
   RAISERROR(N'AccountNumber cannot be associated with more than 1 Account_Key', 16, 1);
   RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I try on this. And yes struzky this is a DW thanks for understanding me : )

Comment: Yes, it worked great!
There is another table (case) where 1 Account_Key can only be related to 1 AccountNumber  meaning 1..1 relation, all other things is the same except that there should be 1..1 relation between...
is that even possible with your trigger?

Comment: @Henrik Please add that to the Question. But that should just be a simple Unique Index (assuming that this is, as you said, another table and not the one that the initial Question was about). Or would it also have multiple dates? Again, please add the details to the Question.

Comment: @Henrik I just updated my answer with something that should work for the new second case..

Comment: Dammit strutzky! What are you? a living Database Engine?  : - )  
Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want:

1. Any given AccountNumber can only be related to one AccountKey
2. Any given AccountKey can be related to multiple AccountNumbers

If this is correct, you can achieve this with a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` that calls a UDF.

EDIT:

Psuedo-logic for the CHECK CONSTRAINT could be:

```
IF EXISTS anotherRow 
WHERE theOtherAccountNumber = thisAccountNumber 
AND theOtherAccountKey <> thisAccountKey
THEN False (do not allow this row to be inserted)
ELSE True (allow the insertion)
```

I would put this logic in a UDF that returns true or false to make the CHECK constraint simpler.

Comment: Yes! for instance 10 Accountnumber can only be related to one AccountKey and one AccountKey can be related to multiple AccountNumbers in that same table.

Comment: Then a CHECK CONSTRAINT is the way to go.   That's how I would do it.  A TRIGGER would also work, but I prefer constraints.

Comment: Sounds good Tab, can you precise it more in some pseodo logic or something? Since I tried a lot of combination with check constraints, thanks!
Should I also use the UDF that you suggested?

Comment: I have added some pseudo-logic to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extra table AccountKeyNumbers (name is your choice of course) with columns Account_Key and Account_Number.

Make Account_Number the primary key.

Note that you can't add an Account_Number twice and therefore, can't link it to two different Account_Keys in this table.

Now, you add an extra unique constraint on Account_Number plus Account_Key. In this table you put all the account numbers and their corresponding keys.

Finally, you define a foreign key on your Accounts table, on the columns Account_Key plus Account_Number, referencing the unique constraint in the AccountKeyNumbers table.

You've now ensured that only valid key/number combinations can be inserted into Accounts and no two AccountKeys can have the same number. We needed the extra unique constraint, which doesn't contribute to the data integrity of the AccountKeyNumbers table, just to enable creating a foreign key, which must point to a primary or unique constraint.